# ValueError: could not convert string to float: in Python 3.10

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

When someone writes a string or a letter, I want the code make them go back, and the code to print "must be a number and bigger than 0 and less than 100", but what actually happens is the code closing. Is there by any chance a fix for this?

```
import time

def main():
    num1 = input("your t76ely\n")
    num2 = input("your num2\n")
    school = input("your school\n")

    num1 = float(num1)
    num2 = float(num2)
    school = float(school)

    if num1 > 100:
        print("must be a number and bigger than 0 and less than 100")
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            main()
    elif num1 < 0:
        print("must be a number and bigger than 0 and less than 100")
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            main()
    if num2 > 100:
        print("must be a number and bigger than 0 and less than 100")
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            main()
    elif num2 < 0:
        print("must be a number and bigger than 0 and less than 100")
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            main()
    if school > 100:
        print("must be a number and bigger than 0 and less than 100")
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            main()
    elif school < 0:
        print("must be a number and bigger than 0 and less than 100")
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            main()
    else:
        r = (40 % 100 * float(num1)) + (30 % 100 * float(num2)) + (30 % 100 * float(school))
    r = r / 100
    print(r)
    print('\nnum1 :', {num1}, '\nnum2 :', {num2}, "\nschool :", {school})

while True:
    main()
    if input("\nWant To continue ? Y/N\n").upper().strip() != "Y":
        break
```

It's showing me this when I try to type for example my name "trais" or a letter or a "string"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python Projects\your mark\mark calculator.py", line 51, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\Python Projects\your mark\mark calculator.py", line 9, in main
    num1 = float(num1)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'trais'
```

Comment: Take a look right here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp#:~:text=The%20try%20block%20lets%20you,when%20there%20is%20no%20error.

Comment: `float` doesn't translate words into numbers; it parses numeric literals. `float('3')` or `float('3.0')` produces the `float` value 3; it cannot work with words from any particular language.

Comment: If you are aware of why that's an error, then you still have to catch the exception it raises to prevent your script from exiting prematurely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [PyInputPlus](https://pypi.org/project/PyInputPlus/). If you are okay with installing library.

> **`float()`** will convert numeric string to float type. Not any other string which is not numerical.

Basic snippet for keep on going until input is correct (without any prompt)

```py
def trial():
    try:
        a=float(input("Enter 0 to 100"))
        print(a,type(a))
    except:
        print("Enter number between 0 to 100")
        trial()
```

Comment: can you show me please how can i add it to my project ?

Comment: Do go through documentation and blogs. It pretty much same and easy to use with more feature.

Answer (score -1):

guys i really don't know how to thank you, i did it thanks for you all i will show the code for those who want to see it

```
import time


def main():
    num1 = input("your num1\n")
    num2 = input("your num2\n")
    school = input("your school\n")
    try:
        num1 = float(num1)
        num2 = float(num2)
        school = float(school)
    except:
        print("must be a number")
        time.sleep(1)
    try:
        if num1 > 100:
            print("must be bigger than 0 and less than 100")
            while True:
                time.sleep(1)
                main()
        elif num1 < 0:
            print("must be bigger than 0 and less than 100")
            while True:
                time.sleep(1)
                main()
        if num2 > 100:
            print("must be bigger than 0 and less than 100")
            while True:
                time.sleep(1)
                main()
        elif num2 < 0:
            print("must be bigger than 0 and less than 100")
            while True:
                time.sleep(1)
                main()
        if school > 100:
            print("must be bigger than 0 and less than 100")
            while True:
                time.sleep(1)
                main()
        elif school < 0:
            print("must be bigger than 0 and less than 100")
            while True:
                time.sleep(1)
                main()
        else:
            r = (40 % 100 * float(num1)) + (30 % 100 * float(num2)) + (30 % 100 * float(school))
        r = r / 100
        print(r)
        print('\nnum1 :', {num1}, '\nnum2 :', {num2}, "\nschool :", {school})
    except:
        while True:
            main()
            time.sleep(1)
            if input("\nWant To continue ? Y/N\n").upper().strip() != "Y":
                break


while True:
    main()
    time.sleep(1)
    if input("\nWant To continue ? Y/N\n").upper().strip() != "Y":
        break
```

what happens here is if you by accident typed a string, the code will not break but you will see an error message like this, and you can use the code more and more!

i used here "try" and "except" method here is a tutorial for it ! [https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp#:~:text=The%20try%20block%20lets%20you,when%20there%20is%20no%20error](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp#:%7E:text=The%20try%20block%20lets%20you,when%20there%20is%20no%20error)

thanks a lot to @Noah

```
your num1
trais
your num2
34
your school
45
must be a number
your num1
```

as you see guys I typed my name and the code told me that it must be a number and you can continue the code with out exiting or breaking "), thanks a lot again

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).