# How can I use a syntax for set of numbers in a single line

Tags: python

```
def punch_your_three_brothers_in_order_of_age(a, b, c):
    list = [a, b, c]
    if type(a) == str:
        return "Please use numbers for each brother's age."
    elif type(b) == str:
        return "Please use numbers for each brother's age."
    elif type(c) == str:
        return "Please use numbers for each brother's age."
    else:
        list.sort(reverse=True)
        A = list
        return "Start with the " + str(A[0]) + " year old, then continue with your " + str(A[1]) + " year old brother."
```

I want the program to return "Please use numbers for each brother's age." when a, b or c is not numeric. I want to code that in a single line, I tried something like this:

```
if type(a, b, c) != int or float:
    print("Please use numbers for each brother's age.")
```

But that code doesn't work. How can I do it within a single line?

Comment: `list = ...` is bad. what if you instead do `type(...) != list` ?

Comment: @rv.kvetch given the OP's limited Python knowledge, you should probably clarify what you mean. Specifically: don't use `list` for a variable name because it shadows a Python built-in of the same name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: could not convert string to float: in Python 3.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72692211/valueerror-could-not-convert-string-to-float-in-python-3-10)

Answer (score 2):

You have the right idea to use the boolean `or` operator. However, it doesn't quite work the way you want. Instead, you need to take the `type()` of each variable one at a time and compare with each type separately:

```
if type(a) != float and type(a) != int:
    print("Please use numbers for each brother's age.")
```

Alternatively, you can use the `not in` operator:

```
if type(a) not in (int, float):
    print("Please use numbers for each brother's age.")
```

Alternatively, you can put the variables in a list:

```
brothers = [a, b, c]

if any(type(bro) not in (float, int) for bro in brothers):
    print("Please use numbers for each brother's age.")
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `all()` rather than `any()` if the intention is to ensure all items in the list are numeric?

Comment: @sj95126 Thanks for the correction. And my `or` should be `and`.

Comment: @sj95126 err...that's still not quite right

Comment: @sj95126 Check now. If I'm thinking correctly now, I was missing the proper negations in my original answer. Of course, I could apply deMorgan to get a variation using `all()` instead.

Comment: Ah, yeah, it needs either `any(..not in...)` or `not all(...)`. Sorry for not being more specific.

Comment: @sj95126 No problem. Thanks for pinging me so that I thought about double checking the logic.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the inputs are strings that may or may not have numeric values (e.g. returned by the `input()`) function, what you want to do is convert them into numbers, and catch any resulting `ValueError`:

```
def punch_your_three_brothers_in_order_of_age(a, b, c):
    try:
        ages = sorted(int(i) for i in [a, b, c])
    except ValueError:
        print("Please use numbers for each brother's age.")
        return
    print(f"Start with the {ages[0]} year old...")
```

If the inputs already have the `int` or `float` type, converting them to `int` won't raise a `ValueError` so this same approach will work fine.

Answer (score -1):

this function checks if all it`s arguments have number type:

```
def is_num(*args):
res = True
for i in args:
    if type(i) not in [float, int]:
        res = False
return res

print(is_num(255, 25235, 213.4))
print(is_num("sdad", 12, 12.5))
```

outputs to console:

```
True
False
```

Answer (score -2):

The easiest solution is to use `or` to create one big line of if checking.

```py
if not ((type(a) in (int, float)) or (type(b) in (int, float)) or (type(c) in (int, float))):
```

But thats a little cumbersome and convoluted, so maybe some checking with `any`?

```py
if any((not type(v) in (int, float) for v in [a, b, c])):
```

Comment: I'm sure you don't mean: `int or float`.

Comment: Right, I accidentally based it off OP's syntax, so yes that should be completely separate checks instead of separated with `or`

Comment: Thank you; retracted my downvote; surely whoever added the other one will do likewise if they happen by and see the code is now correct.